# Svelte Materialify library doesn't load theme styles

Tags: sass, svelte, sveltekit

I am using the latest Svelte Kit as well as the Svelte Materialify library for fast UI development. The library documentation described the theme development method:

> You want to customise some SCSS variables? Worry not, just put them in the **_material-theme.scss** you had created:
>
> ```
> $primary-color: #004d26;
> ...
> ```

But this method didn't work. Even after I specified the folder in the Svelte Kit configuration and also installed all the dependencies:

```
preprocess: preprocess({
    scss: {
        includePaths: [resolve('./theme')] // resolve imported from path
    },
    postcss: {
        plugins: [postAutoprefixer]
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a style tag with a "global" and lang="scss" attribute in your __layout.svelte and then import the variables file there.

```
<style global lang="scss">
    @import '../styles/variables';
    @import '../styles/main';

    .date-picker {
        outline-color: $input-outline-color;
    }
</style>
```

This has worked for me to make my custom variables accessible in main.scss and this tag in __layout.scss. If you need those variables in any other component down the tree, you need to reimport those variables, IMO. This should not be a problem in regard of duplication of styles as long as you do not add any style rules to the variable file.

Update:

While the approach above might work, it is not the recommended solution. An error message by the compiler guided me to the right solution further explained here:
[svelte documentation](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/faq.md#where-should-i-put-my-global-styles)

Directly import the main.scss stylesheet into your "main.js" file maybe also the __layout file in SvelteKit

```
<script lang="ts">
    import '../app.css';
    import '../styles/main.scss';
</script>

<slot />

<style global lang="scss">
</style>
```